# Points and polylines representation of coordinates in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates

I am working on the "Jakarta Bay", Indonesia. I have a shapefile for the Indonesian coastline and I clipped my region of interest using an appropriate polygon. I also have points that are located within the bay.

When I want to represent both layers together, I realize it is not possible because they have different coordinates format (see images). I don't understand it as I chose manually to set the SCR to EPSG:4326 (OTF). The project SCR is the same.

If I make a zoom to layer I can see each layers individually, but it looks like they are not in the same location.

Looking to the coordinates show different results (see images).

[image: The points located in the Jakarta bay]

[image: The coastline of the Jakarta bay]

I would like to have coordinates as for the points for both layers (East, North) because I can show them in the OpenLayers plugin.

I have the feeling my scale is a bit strange for the coastline layer...

Comment: Right click to both layers and choose "Save as..." then choose WGS84 for both. Now add both layers to the map canvas.

Comment: This doesn't change anything. My new layers are identical to the old ones.

Comment: You have to reset the layers to their original projection with `Set CRS for Layer` before using `Save As ...`.

Comment: AndreJ is right: I had to reset the CRS to the original one and then I could save to a different CRS. Because I skipped this step I had an error with out-bounding coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your coastlines screenshot shows coordinate x=704137, y=9324475. I guess this could be EPSG:32748 "WGS 84 / UTM Zone 48S". Change the CRS in the layer properties from layer coastlines, on tab "General" and check if both layers line up.

In the comments you state you messed with the projection file but kept the original one. So it will be easiest to restore this file and add the layer again in QGIS.

The other way is, like I wrote in the first paragraph, to change the CRS in the layer properties. This will not reproject/recalculate the coordinate numbers like "save as", but will show the geometries at another place in the world.

Don't use "save as" with another CRS, because this assumes the geometries are already shown at the right place on the map. With "save as" you reproject the layer, that is you calculate coordinates for another system without changing the position on the earth. The error you cite in the comment is because six and seven digit coordinates make no sense in EPSG:4326 (having coordinates x in [-180, +180] and y in [-90, +90]) and can't be reprojected.

Comment: I can't save my layer to EPSG:32748. I get the following message:

L'export du fichier vectoriel a échoué.
Erreur : Impossible de transformer un point pendant le dessin de l'entité avec l'id '0'. L'écriture est stoppée. (Exception: Poursuivre la transformation de
(12264.476559, 162939.081252)
PROJ.4:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to  +proj=utm +zone=48 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
Erreur: latitude or longitude exceeded limits)

Comment: "Erreur: latitude or longitude exceeded limits". I probably can't do the SCR conversion because my coordinates are outbounded.

Comment: This is my projection file: GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]

Comment: But I think I should have the following projection (original one before I made manipulations): PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_48S",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",10000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",105.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Comment: I edited my answer. @ZKB

Comment: It would be better to through away your project and start again with the original datasources in a new project.

Comment: In my case I messed up with the coordinates, but lucky I had other shapesfiles that had the same projection so I found it again. In case I could not do the latter, is there a way to find again the original CRS ?